# Turn off auto style in tables [Tinymce]

Tags: tinymce

As there is no more Tinymce forum if I can ask is there way to turn off in tables function with adding style="width: or height:" to the source code.

Thank you

Comment: FYI - There is a TinyMCE Forum (http://archive.tinymce.com/forum/viewforum.php?id=1) ... we will be moving it to a new TinyMCE Community platform in the next 3-5 weeks (http://archive.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=36617).

Answer (score 10):

I worked around this by adding the following to the tinymce configuration:

```
invalid_styles: 'width height'
```

This strips width and height stlyes from all elements, which worked for my use case. I believe you may be able to specify which elements this applies to as well (e.g. table, tr, th, td).

```
invalid_styles: { 
    'table': 'width height', 
    'tr' : 'width height',
    'th' : 'width height',
    'td' : 'width height'
}
```

See https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-filtering/#invalid_styles

Comment: invalid_styles: {
    'table': 'width height',
    'tr' : 'width height',
    'th' : 'width height',
    'td' : 'width height'
}

Comment: Thanks @migli - I have added those to my own answer (which I stumbled upon two years after posting it, when searching for the same issue again!)

Comment: It works for me only half. It stop tinymce to add height but still is adding width when create the table :(

Comment: thanks @ChrisWheeler this is helpful and also for other elements too

Comment: Updated link to the docs: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-filtering/#invalid_styles

Comment: Thanks @HosseinDehnokhalaji - I have updated my answer with the new docs link.

Answer (score 0):

When you first insert a table TinyMCE should not be using a width or height to define the table.  When you drag to resize the column width or row height it will add these in order to set the width or height of the column/row as needed.

Are you seeing this issue when first inserting the table via Table / Insert?  Are you seeing this after resizing a row or column?

EDIT: If this is happening when you are "just typing text" I have a hunch what might be happening...

When you insert a new/empty table there will be no inline styles on it at all.  If you just start typing text into cells there should continue to not be any inline styles.

If, however, you use your mouse to move into a new/empty cell sometimes (if you click on the cell border and not inside the cell) you will see the borders momentarily turn blue when you click your mouse.  When you see that blue appear TinyMCE is trying to set the "size" of the row or column on which you clicked.  If instead of clicking into the small/empty cell you use your keyboard to move between cells I bet you won't get any inline styles.

The clicking on the borders is trigging code to handle manual resize events via the mouse.

Comment: I using tinymce to prepare proposal for customer . So I copy html tinymce source without width and height . When I close source code and open again there is no style parameters. But when I start editing table it adding itself. I'm not using drag to resize but getting the style width and height . So the only way to fix this is edit code again and remove from source all style parameters.

Comment: What are you doing within the table that causes TinyMCE to add these parameters?  Can you determine which actions are causing the editor to add the inline styles?

Comment: Yep , just replacing what is in table for example table with Product Name | Description | Net Price | Total Price . When I remove text and start writing something different it adding style to table. When I change without removing first letter/number it's fine.  Will try update Tinymce to tle latest . Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: @PatrykGrzyb see my edit above ... perhaps this is the issue?